# JSF wrapping the <h:outputLabel> text w.r.t to starting index of the its own in next line

Tags: java, jsf, jakarta-ee, jsf-2, primefaces

I have a an outputlable `<h:outputLabel  id="label1" value="Project Name"/>`.Next to that I have another `<h:outputLabel id="label2" value="#{XXBean.details.projectName}"/>` 
Both labes are located inside a `<p:fieldset>`
label2 will get rendered based on the value in bean.
label2 is getting wrapped in the next line but the wrapped text should start from the starting index of the label2 not from starting index of label1.

I tried `<h:outputLabel  style="white-space: pre;word-wrap: break-word;" />` 
but it shows the label2 in a straight line and its extending the size of the fieldset.
And its not wrapping it as per the expected results given below.

```
Actual result I am getting : 

 label1:labellabel2label2label2label2label2label2label2label2label2
 label2label2label2label2

Expected :

label1:labellabel2label2label2label2label2label2label2label2label2
       label2label2label2label2
```

Please advise me to get the Expected  output.

Comment: That might depend on the width, you are giving to your labels through wrapper.

Comment: I am not providing any width to the label2 as you can see above.<h:outputLabel id="label2" value="#{XXBean.details.projectName}"/>

Comment: But where are you wrapping your two lables? I mean to ask that you should put them in separate divs or spans.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

the first label has a fix width (its only "Project Name" value) and the second one depend on the width from labels wrapper (e.g. fieldset).

```
#label1{
    display: inline-block;
    vertical-align: top;
}
#label2{
    display: inline-block;
    width: 66%;
}
```

Set correct label2 width depends from the wrapper.

Alternative:
Display labels as a table cell.

```
#label1{
    display: table-cell;
    vertical-align: top;
}
#label2{
    display: table-cell;
}
```